# How to return a view from a class which does not inherit a contoller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I just want to return a view based from this class, when policy has been violated (using [FluentSecurity](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity))

```
public class RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler : IPolicyViolationHandler
{
    public ActionResult Handle(PolicyViolationException exception)
    {
        //return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(exception.Message);
        return View("../Shared/Error");
    }
}
```

but return View does not exist in current context.

Any help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply returning **`new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };`** should work!